# Add local notification plugin to Visual Studio Cordova

Tags: xml-parsing, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, visual-studio-cordova, cordova-plugin-file

when I try to add local notification plugin 
(https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications)
to my visual studio cordova project, I got this error message -

> Visual studio was unable to parse plugin.xml. Please ensure plugin.xml
>   exists and contains no errors.

What should I do to install this plugin? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a problem with the plugin.xml or VS2015. The plugin `<engines` is using "fuzzy" matches and it should work according to http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.1.1/plugin_ref/spec.html

```
    <engines>
    <engine name="cordova" version=">=3.6.0" />
    <engine name="cordova" version="<4.0.0" />
</engines>
```

Unfortunately, the `<engine name="cordova" version="<4.0.0" />` element is preventing VS2015 from loading the plugin using config.xml > Plugins > Custom

[image]
[image]
**Temporary Fix:**

1. Download the plugin locally to the projects `plugins` folder
2. Remove `<engine name="cordova" version="<4.0.0" />` from `cordova-plugin-local-notifications.plugin.xml`
3. Retrieve the plugin using `config.xml` Plugins > Custom > Local

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am able to add the plugin by following your solution, but when I build, I go the following error in output, 1>  Installing "de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification" for android
1>  Running command: C:\app\Kaobei\10052015\Shhh...ItWorks_\Shhh...ItWorks\platforms\android\cordova\version.bat
1>  Command finished with error code 0: C:\app\...\platforms\android\cordova\version.bat1>                 Dependencies detected, iterating through them...
1>  Dependent plugin "cordova-plugin-device" already fetched, using that version.

Comment: continued :                                                                                                 1>  Dependent plugin "cordova-plugin-device" already installed on android.
1>  Dependent plugin "cordova-plugin-android-support-v4" not fetched, retrieving then installing.
1>  Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-android-support-v4" via plugin registry
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========